# ReactJS Typescript pass props in Link react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm using react with react-router-dom. I want to pass the property is an array in 'Link' of react-router-dom

```
<Link to={{pathname: `/{myURL}`, state:  myArray}}></Link>
```

This is my code to receive the property

```
const location = useLocation<Location>()
const test = location.state
```

When I console.log(test), the result is correct. But when I use .map to display the array

```
{test && test.map(t => (...))}
```

I have error like this

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Location'.
```

How can I solve my problem? Thanks

Comment: `Location` should be `Location[]`

Comment: on which property are you using `.map`? Please share the full code

Comment: When you get this error `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Location'.`, are you sure you haven't written `location.map` instead of `location.state.map`? Also, to debug, you could try `const location = useLocation<Location>(); console.log(location);` to see what's happening.

Comment: @rshepp I sure write location.state

Comment: Oh, I see what's going on. The generic `T` in `useLocation<T>` is probably meant to be the type of `state`, ie. the type of your array.

Comment: @rshepp wow great, it works, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic `T` in `useLocation<T>` defines the expected type of `location.state`.

```
// Change this:
const location = useLocation<Location>();

// To this:
const location = useLocation<myArrayType>();
```